# Is it really possible to append data to a text file in MFC's by using CFile and CStdio classes?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc, file-handling

Is it really possible to append data to a text file in MFC's  by using `CFile` and `CStdio` classes ??If yes, then how ??

I used the following code to append the data, but it just gives the latest(last entered) data..

```
UpdateData(TRUE);
CStdioFile file_object;//(L"D://Docs//Temp.txt",
    CFile::modeCreate | CFile::modeReadWrite | CFile::modeRead); 
CString str = L"D://Docs//Temp.txt";
CString fc1, fc2;

BOOL bFile = file_object.Open(str, 
    CFile::modeCreate | CFile::modeReadWrite | CFile::modeRead);
if (bFile)
    file_object.Seek(file_object.GetLength(), CFile::end);

fc1.Format(L"%f", m_CelTemp);
file_object.WriteString(L"Temp in Celsius is:");     
file_object.WriteString(fc1);
file_object.WriteString(L"\n");

fc2.Format(L"%f", m_FarTemp);
file_object.WriteString(L"Temp in Fahrenheit is:");      
file_object.WriteString(fc2);
file_object.WriteString(L"\n");

UpdateData(FALSE);
```

Comment: Your code wouldn't compile, there are glaring errors.

Comment: like?? @BarmakShemirani

Comment: Try it. See also the section about a minimal but complete example in the posting guidelines.

Comment: @UlrichEckhart but please tell me, what should i try ??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the sample code you can try

```
CStdioFile file;
file.Open(_T("_FILE_PATH_HERE"),CFile::modeCreate|CFile::modeWrite|CFile::modeNoTruncate);
file.SeekToEnd();
file.WriteString(_T("Write Text Here\r\n")); // \r\n to move the cursor to the next line
file.Close();
```

**CFile::modeCreate** Creates a new file if no file exists.; If the file already exists, CFileException is raised.

**CFile::modeNoTruncate** Creates a new file if no file exists; otherwise, if the file already exists, it is attached to the CFile object.

**CFile::modeWrite** Requests write access only.

**file.SeekToEnd();** Sets the value of the file pointer to the logical end of the file.

Comment: NoTruncate doesn't create the file if no file exists.  It's a mistake in the documentation.  Known since 2008, which is funny.

Comment: `modeCreate` overwrites the existing file. How did this ever work?

Comment: If `CFile::modeCreate` throws an exception if the file already exists, then your code would never append to an existing file.

Comment: @CBGraham
Tested CStdioFile::modeCreate | CStdioFile::modeWrite | CStdioFile::modeNoTruncate and it creates files if they don't exist already.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `CFile::SeekToEnd()` method to set the value of the file pointer to the logical end of the file in order to append data.

Here is an example:

```
CStdioFile f;
CString sDataToWrite(_T("Data\r\n"));
if(f.Open(_T("C:\\Files\\file.txt"), CFile::modeCreate | CFile::modeNoTruncate | CFile::modeWrite)) 
{
      f.SeekToEnd();
      f.WriteString(sDataToWrite);  
}
f.Close();
```

Comment: i tried this also, but while debugging i checked that the cursor pointer is not going to the end after i enter the first set of details.

Comment: The problem is that you're using `Seek` method with wrong parameters instead of `SeekToEnd()`

Comment: okay, lets assume that i dont use the **Seek** method, then what should i do, any alternative method ??

Comment: `SeekToEnd()` is the way to go: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa270549(v=vs.60).aspx

Comment: I've updated the answer to provide you with an example on how to use it

Answer (score 0):

First off, what you posted wouldn't compile, starting with line #3. Please post real code.

Best guess is that the problem lies with `CFile::modeCreate` which "*Creates a new file if no file exists.; If the file already exists, CFileException is raised.*" (see reference docs at [CFile::CFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cz0a83sb.aspx)). You probably want `CFile::modeNoTruncate` which is "*open existing*".

Answer (score 0):

Yes It's possible to Append Data using CFile and CStdioFile.
You have to use

> FileObj.Open(L"FileName.txt",CFile ::modeCreate |               CFile::modeWrite | CFile::modeNoTruncate);

simple Example

```
CFile FileObj;
//CStdioFile FileObj;

//  FileObj.Open(L"FileName.txt",CStdioFile ::modeCreate | CStdioFile::modeWrite | CStdioFile::modeNoTruncate);
FileObj.Open(L"FileName.txt",CFile ::modeCreate | CFile::modeWrite | CFile::modeNoTruncate);
FileObj.SeekToEnd();
CString Message = m_strName ;       // Whetever Your Message
FileObj.Write(Message,Message.GetLength());
FileObj.Flush();
FileObj.Close();
```